# Size of generating set of a generalized dihedral group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Consider a generalized dihedral group. Say, we take $G= H \rtimes \mathbb Z_2$, where H is an abelian group of order $p^m$ with $p$ odd and such that all non-trivial elements have order $p$. $\mathbb Z_2$ acts on H in such a way that non-zero elements of $\mathbb Z_2$ maps element of H to its inverse. What is the size of the minimal generating set for this group? I believe it is n+1, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245505

Answer (score 1):

Notation: for minimal generator set I mean a set that does not contain a proper generating subset.
It is well known that a finite abelian groups is a direct product of suitable cyclic subgroups. Say
\begin{gather}
H=C_1 \times \dots \times C_n
\end{gather}
The action of $<i> \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$ on $H$ is just the inversion
\begin{gather}
(g_1, \dots, g_n)x=(g_1^{-1}, \dots, g_n^{-1})
\end{gather}
Suppose $C_i=<g_i>$, then $\{i,g_1, \dots ,g_n \}$ is a minimal set of generators, indeed remove, for example, $g_1$, then since $C_i$ are $i$-invariant you get that 
\begin{gather} \langle i,g_1 \dots \hat{g_i} \dots g_n \rangle = \left( C_1 \times \dots \hat{C_i} \dots \times C_n\right) \rtimes \langle i \rangle < G
\end{gather} 
So as you can see, the size of a minimal set of generators depends only upon the length of the decomposition of $H$ in product of cyclic groups.
If you are looking for the minimal cardinality of a generating set, the problem is a bit more complicated, but I think that you can find the solution here:
[Minimal generation for finite abelian groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88106/minimal-generation-for-finite-abelian-groups)